# Problems with QGIS plugin traceDigitize on Mac?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, trace

I'm trying to get the [traceDigitize](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/traceDigitize/) plugin to work with QGIS 2.0.1 on my Mac while [following this tutorial](http://darrencope.com/2011/10/13/qgis-trace-edit-tool/) but I get this error as soon as I ctrl-click:

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oskarlin/.qgis2/python/plugins/traceDigitize/traceDigitize.py", line 135, in createFeature
    if (geom.isGeosValid()):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isGeosValid'

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]

QGIS version:
2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, f738351

Python path: ['/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python', '/Users/oskarlin/.qgis2/python', '/Users/oskarlin/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins', '/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/B/Python/2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/Python/2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/fTools/tools']
```

Could this be a Mac specific problem or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using OSX version 10.9 (Mavericks) with QGIS 2.0.1 and [GDAL Complete framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks).

Comment: what Version of Mac OSX do you have and did you install the correct frameworks? Jörn

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Jörn, I've added OS and GDAL version above.

Comment: Sorry for mistaken comment and answer. Well, I work here still with Mountain Lion with no problems until now. Is it possible that there are problems with Maverick? Did you try that plugin before? Jörn

Comment: Thats me again. I work with Mountain Lion and QGIS 2.0.1 I installed the plugin and it worked fine in the beginning. But now I get the same error message like you.

Comment: I have filed a bug report on the plugins website...